# Adding Filter to ICollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I add an extra parameter to my predicate to filter my CollectionView?

Here's how I filter my collectionview:

```
_customerCollection = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Customers);
_customerCollection.Filter += new Predicate<object>(ShowMale);

private bool ShowMale(object pr)
{
    if (pr == null) return false;
    Customer c = pr as Customer;
    return c.Gender == "male";
}
```

This works. My question is how can I add an extra parameter to my predicate? Say, I want to pass the string "male". Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Filter` property cannot be set to something else than a `Predicate<object>`, i.e. a method that accepts an `object` and returns a `bool`, but you can retrieve any values you want in the method.

So instead of trying to pass something to the method, you could define the `string` as a member of the same class in which the `Predicate<object>` is defined and retrieve it from there, e.g.:

```
public string Gender { get; set; } = "male";

private bool ShowMale(object pr)
{
    if (pr == null) return false;
    Customer c = pr as Customer;
    return c.Gender == this.Gender;
}
```

In the above sample, you could of course bind the `Gender` property to a control in the view that sets its value dynamically.

Comment: That's what I initially thinks. thanks @mm8 I figured that I can't pass argument to the eventHandler but I can catch other members to make a conditional statements. This not actually what fits my situation, but this is the correct way on handling predicates conditions. So I'm accepting your answer for future audiences. Than you!